# Does PyQT5 QTimer timer.start() it overlap functions or it waits until end of Function?

Tags: python, function, pyqt5, qtimer

I use QTimer, but my question here is that the function I call every 400ms runs between 1-2 seconds. Here, does the QTimer.start() method wait for the called function to finish or rerun it repeatedly (overlapping)?

https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html

"If Qt is unable to deliver the requested number of timer clicks, it will silently discard some."
What does it mean?

Should I use timer.stop() in start of function and then in end of the function use timer.start() again?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow and congrats on your first question. Make sure you read the guidelines for posting questions. Share information that might help us help you, e.g. code, data, desired output. And remember, post your own efforts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Premise: you're using Qt4, which is considered obsolete since 2015.

The `start()` method is not blocking, so it will not "wait" anything, it just starts the timer. What could be actually "waiting" is the possible return from the function connected to the timeout signal.

It is explained more clearly in the [Qt5 documentation about QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#accuracy-and-timer-resolution):

> All timer types may time out later than expected if the system is busy or unable to provide the requested accuracy. In such a case of timeout overrun, Qt will emit timeout() only once, even if multiple timeouts have expired, and then will resume the original interval.

This means that if the thread in which the QTimer has been created is occupied when the timeout *should* be emitted, the signal will be actually emitted as soon as the thread allows it, then it will restart the timer with the specified interval.

Take this small example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys
from time import sleep
from random import getrandbits

def timeout():
    print('timeout, elapsed: {}'.format(
        elapsed.elapsed() * .001))
    elapsed.start()
    if getrandbits(1):
        print('waiting one second')
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print('no wait')

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
elapsed = QtCore.QElapsedTimer()
elapsed.start()
timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=250, timeout=timeout)
timer.start()
app.exec_()
```

As said before, the "waiting" is *possible*: in the example above we are only using the main Qt thread, but when the connection is done on a function/slot that resides on another thread, Qt doesn't wait for its completion.

In the following example, the timer is connected twice, the first to a simple non blocking function, the second to a function on an object that is on another thread:

```
class ObjectOnAnotherThread(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.count = 0
        self.elapsed = QtCore.QElapsedTimer()
        self.elapsed.start()

    def timeout(self):
        self.count += 1
        print('thread timeout #{}, elapsed: {}'.format(
            self.count, self.elapsed.elapsed() * .001))
        self.elapsed.start()
        if getrandbits(1):
            print('waiting one second')
            sleep(1)
        else:
            print('no wait')

def timeout():
    global simpleCount
    simpleCount += 1
    print('simple timeout #{}, elapsed: {}'.format(
        simpleCount, elapsed.elapsed() * .001))
    elapsed.start()

simpleCount = 0
app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

thread = QtCore.QThread()
obj = ObjectOnAnotherThread()
obj.moveToThread(thread)
thread.start()

elapsed = QtCore.QElapsedTimer()
elapsed.start()

timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=250)
timer.timeout.connect(obj.timeout)
timer.timeout.connect(timeout)
timer.start()
app.exec_()
```

You'll see that the timeout is not blocked: the "simple timeout" gets called without any delay, while the thread will receive timeouts almost instantly whenever it was blocked, and **all** subsequent timeout received in the meantime will also be processed.

This is because whenever a signal is called on a different thread, Qt will *queue* the signal automatically. You can "force" queueing for any connection by using `signal.connect(function, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)`, but this is generally not required, and will not work anyway if the object is not on a separate thread.